# Angular2 material design mdtabs with router

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular-material2

I can't make tabs for routing work ([from angular material 2 docs](https://material.angular.io/components/component/tabs)):

**component**:

```
export class AppComponent {
  navLinks: [
    '/groups',
    '/objects'
  ]
}
```

**html**:

```
<nav md-tab-nav-bar>
  <a md-tab-link
     *ngFor="let link of navLinks"
     [routerLink]="link"
     routerLinkActive #rla="routerLinkActive"
     [active]="rla.isActive">
    {{tabLink.label}}
  </a>
</nav>

<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

no errors in the log
may be it's obvious, but still...

Comment: what is that you are expectation? I too tried this similar approach but failed so fixed it in a different way. So I can help you out in this

Comment: @Aravind expectations are to have tabs for navigate through app, I have two components mapped to ['/groups', '/objects'], have link and label for them, and dont know how to run it ;) . workaround is to use my own style for A tag ofc)

Comment: two components in two tabs and you navigate between them through your routing url? correct?

Comment: yes) two components for each own tab to navigate

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It works perfectly fine with the below code

```
<nav md-tab-nav-bar aria-label="weather navigation links">
    <a md-tab-link
        *ngFor="let routeLink of routeLinks; let i = index"
         [routerLink]="routeLink.link"
         [active]="activeLinkIndex === i"
         (click)="activeLinkIndex = i">
         {{routeLink.label}}
     </a>
</nav>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

My component code looks like,

```
export class App {
  routeLinks:any[];
  activeLinkIndex = 0;
  constructor(private router: Router) {
    this.routeLinks = [
    {label: 'Welcome', link: 'welcome'},
    {label: 'Home', link: 'home'}];

  }
}
```

**[LIVE DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/qIkkBBbx7ctpBA5nvg99?p=preview)**

Answer (score 4):

I think above code snippets do not work with material design. Because i have checked that . But below code works perfectly with material design

```typescript
import { Router } from "@angular/router";

constructur(router:Router){}

public selectedTab(e) {
        switch (e.index) {
        case 0:
            this.router.navigateByUrl('/');
            break;
        case 1:
            this.router.navigateByUrl('/contact');
            break;
        case 2:
            this.router.navigateByUrl('/about');
            break;

        default:
            console.log('material-design-mdtabs-with-router');
            break;
        }
    }
```

```html
<md-tab-group (focusChange)="selectedTab($event)">
            <md-tab>
                <template md-tab-label>
                    Home
                </template>
            </md-tab>
            <md-tab>
                    <template md-tab-label>
                        Contact
                    </template>
                </md-tab>
                <md-tab>
                    <template md-tab-label>
                        About
                    </template>
                </md-tab>
            </md-tab-group>

<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Comment: This will work when tabs are manually clicked but fail when the user tries to hit browsers back button. It won't highlight to the previously selected tab on back click.

Answer (score 4):

The demo example in your code should be changed a little bit and will work too:

```
<nav md-tab-nav-bar>
  <a md-tab-link
     *ngFor="let tabLink of tabLinks; let i = index"
     [routerLink]="tabLink.link"
     routerLinkActive #rla="routerLinkActive"
     [active]="rla.isActive">
    {{tabLink.label}}
  </a>
</nav>
```

and in the controller define tabLinks:

```
export class AppComponent {
  tabLinks = [
    {label: 'Groups', link: '/groups'},
    {label: 'Objects', link: '/objects'}
  ]; 
...
```

Comment: It's interesting how it will work with named router-outlet?